I want to view my DS160 application form after submission
I have submitted a DS160 form, and I want to view my application. But when I retrieve the application, only the confirmation can be printed or emailed, the print application tab is not working. I have not scheduled the appointment and only submitted the DS260 form. So, how can I view the application?
